# How do you best simplify $(\omega + 1) \cdot \omega^{2}$?

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

I am currently reading "An Introduction to Set Theory" by Hrbacek and Jech. I have come to an exercise that I am having trouble with. The exercise asks the reader to simplify three ordinal arithmetic expressions. I am having trouble simplifying the last expression.
The last expression is given below :
\begin{equation}
(\omega + 1) \cdot \omega^{2}
\end{equation}
Here $\omega$ represents the natural numbers (the smallest limit ordinal).
I am not sure how to simplify this, my attempt so far is given below :
\begin{align}
(\omega + 1) \cdot \omega^{2} 
 & = (\omega + 1) \cdot (\omega^{2}) \\
 & = (\omega + 1) \cdot (\omega \cdot \omega)\\
 & = \left( (\omega + 1) \cdot \omega \right) \cdot \omega \\
 & = \left( \sup\left( \{(\omega + 1) \cdot n \; \mid \; n \in \boldsymbol{N} \} \right) \right) \cdot \omega
\end{align}
I'm not sure where to go from here (assuming what I've done so far is a reasonable path to the solution).

Can someone help with this ?

Comment: This is good so far. What can you say about $(\omega+1)\cdot n$ for finite $n$ (say, $n=2,3,...$)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following on from where you left off:

For finite $n$, we have
\begin{align*}
(\omega+1)\cdot n &= \underbrace{(\omega+1)+(\omega+1)+ \dots + (\omega+1)}_{n\text{ times}}\\
&= \omega + \underbrace{(1+\omega) + \dots + (1+\omega)}_{n-1\text{ times}}+1\\
&= \omega\cdot n + 1.
\end{align*}
So $(\omega+1)\cdot \omega = \sup_{n\in \omega} (\omega\cdot n + 1) =  \sup_{n\in \omega} (\omega\cdot n) = \omega^2$. (The second equality follows from the observation that $\omega\cdot n \leq \omega\cdot n+1\leq \omega\cdot (n+1)$ for all $n$, so the sequences are mutually cofinal.)

Thus $(\omega+1)\cdot \omega^2 = ((\omega+1)\cdot \omega)\cdot \omega = \omega^2\cdot \omega = \omega^3$.

Comment: I do not get the step where you say both sequences are mutually cofinal. Could you elaborate further?

Comment: @cut which parts do you need me to explain? (a) what mutually cofinal means, (b) how to see these two sequences are mutually cofinal, or (c) why mutually cofinal implies the sequences have the same supremum?

Comment: Just part (c). (a) and (b) are clear, thanks.

Comment: @cut suppose sequences $(a_i)$ and $(b_i)$ are mutually cofinal. Then for all $i$, there exists $j$ such that $a_i\leq b_j$, so $a_i\leq\sup(b_j)$. Since this is true for all $i$, $\sup(a_i)\leq\sup(b_j)$. Now the same argument with $a$ and $b$ exchanged shows the suprema are equal.

Comment: Of course. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For any successor ordinal $\:\alpha<\omega^2$, there is
\begin{align}
(\omega+1)\cdot\alpha&=\underbrace{(\omega +1)+(\omega +1)+\cdots+(\omega +1)}_{\alpha}
\\
&=\underbrace{\omega +(1+\omega)+\cdots+(1+\omega) }_{\alpha}+1
\\
&=\underbrace{\omega +\omega+\cdots+\omega}_{\alpha}+1
\\
&=\omega \cdot \alpha+1
\\
&<\omega^3
\end{align}
Since for any successor ordinal $\:\gamma<\omega^3$, there is a successor ordinal $\:\alpha<\omega^2\:$ that
$$
(\omega+1) \cdot \alpha=\omega \cdot \alpha+\alpha>\gamma\quad\text{and}\quad(\omega+1) \cdot \alpha<\omega^3
$$
So we have
$$
(\omega +1)\cdot \omega^2=\sup\{(\omega+1)\alpha:\alpha<\omega^2\}=\omega^3
$$

Comment: The computation you show only works if $\alpha$ is a successor ordinal.

Comment: How do we know that $\omega \cdot \alpha + 1 < \omega^{3}$ ?

Comment: I modified the answer. Since $\alpha<\omega^2, \:\omega\cdot\alpha<\omega^3$