# Does the equality $\omega\cdot(\omega+1)=(\omega+1)\cdot\omega$ hold?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

By [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4257701/736008) answer I knkow that the equality
$$
(\omega+1)\cdot\omega=\omega^3
$$
holds whereas by the definition of ordinal multiplication I know that the equality
$$
\omega\cdot(\omega+1)=\omega^2+\omega
$$
holds: so it seems to me that the inequality
$$
\omega^2+\omega<\omega^3
$$
holds so that the equality
$$
\omega\cdot(\omega+1)=(\omega+1)\cdot\omega
$$
does not hold but I was not able to prove or disprove this. So could someone prove or disprove if  $\omega\cdot(\omega+1)$ and $(\omega+1)\cdot\omega$ are equal or not, please?

Comment: You seem to have misread the cited answer.

Comment: The cited answer shows that$$(\omega+1)\cdot \omega=\omega^2$$(not $\omega^3$) hence it is $>\omega^2+\omega=\omega\cdot(\omega+1)$.

Comment: The cited answer was about $(\omega + 1)\cdot \omega^2$ (not $(\omega + 1)\omega$) being equal to $\omega^3$.  It was part of the cited answer that $(\omega + 1)\omega=\omega^2$.   I think $\omega(\omega+1)=(\omega + 1)\omega$ should be simple (although it's not my strong suit).

Comment: @AnneBauval You are right: I got confused. So actually I hat to prove the following inequality
$$
(\omega+1)\cdot\omega=\omega^2<\omega^2+\omega=\omega\cdot(\omega^2+1)
$$
right?  So I know that $0<\omega$ so that by monotonicity $\omega^2\le\omega^2+\omega$ but I cannot see the strictly inequality: how I can prove it?

Comment: $\omega^2+\omega\ge\omega^2+1>\omega^2$. The last inequality is strict because one is a successor ordinal and the other one is a limit ordinal.

Comment: @AnneBauval Perfect: thanks for elucidations. :-)

Comment: @fleablood $\omega(\omega+1)<(\omega + 1)\omega$: see proof in previous comments. Maybe you should delete your comment?

Comment: @Antonio $$(\omega+1)\cdot\omega=\omega^2<\omega^2+\omega=\omega\cdot(\omega+1),$$ not $\omega\cdot(\omega^{\color{red}2}+1)$.

Comment: Like I said.  Not my strong suit.  Makes sense though.

Comment: @AnneBauval You're right, I wrote too quickly.

Comment: Antonio, in general it's always true that if $\beta > 0$, then $\alpha < \alpha + \beta$. How to prove this depends on your definitions. The "synthetic" interpretation is the fact that a well-ordered set is not isomorphic to any of its proper initial segments.